# Depth-First Search puzzle

Tags: java, depth-first-search

Not sure how to implement depth first search algorithmn into my code. Here is an example of breadth first search algorithm solving a [8 puzzle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/15_puzzle):

```
    public direction[] Solve(nPuzzle puzzle) {
        //This method uses the fringe as a queue.
        //Therefore, nodes are searched in order of cost, with the lowest cost
        // unexplored node searched next.
        //-----------------------------------------

        //put the start state in the Fringe to get explored.
        addToFrontier(puzzle.StartState);


        ArrayList<PuzzleState> newStates = new ArrayList<PuzzleState>();

        while(Frontier.size() > 0)
        {
            //get the next item off the fringe
            PuzzleState thisState = popFrontier();

            //is it the goal item?
            if(thisState.equals(puzzle.GoalState))
            {
                //We have found a solution! return it!
                return thisState.GetPathToState();
            }
            else
            {
                //This isn't the goal, just explore the node
                newStates = thisState.explore();

                for(int i = 0; i < newStates.size(); i++)
                {
                    //add this state to the fringe, addToFringe() will take care of duplicates
                    addToFrontier(newStates.get(i));
                }
            }
        }

        //No solution found and we've run out of nodes to search
        //return null.
        return null;
    }
```

There is more code [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1YyabfcSNIodGMh7djygJHvCMmBjJNfoh)
Would really appreciate any help

Comment: What do you need help with? What is not working in the code?

Comment: I need to implement a depth first search algorithm which solves an 8-puzzle. I'm not sure how continue to expand the child nodes until it reaches the end or finds a solution. Where the Breadth First Search 'explores' the current state by adding Up,Down,Left,Right states to newStates then they get added to the frontier to be explored. How would I instead continue to explore the child states. So for example explore the up Up state then Up,Up state and then Up,Up,Up then Up,Up,Left. Instead exploring the Up state, then Left state, then Right

Answer (score 0):

a. The main difference in implementation is:  in DFS  the nodes to be explored are stored in a stck, while in BFS they are stored in a queue. 
b. For the puzzle you are trying to solve I think BFS is more appropriate because you are searching for the **shortest** path.

For more help post [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we do not have to do a lot of guesswork.